# Can I get my resting bonus back after curing my Lycanthropy?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

After I have cured my Lycanthropy, can I regain the resting bonus I lost by becoming a werewolf?

Answer (score 3):

On my character the sleeping bonuses came back on their own as soon as my Lycanthropy was cured.

On a side note if you are using the lover's stone it also prevents the sleeping bonus, so you would need to change to a different standing stone power.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, and yes, you would have to give up your Lycanthropy.

There are two methods for curing Lycanthropy. If the first does not work, the second may prove more successful.

1. At the end of the Companions questline, you have the option of curing Kodlak Whitemane of Lycanthropy. In the interest of avoiding spoilers, I won't say any more, but you can repeat the same process used for yourself.
2. Alternatively, if you are on PC, you can use console commands. Typing
   `player.removespell 00092C48` will remove the Beast Form spell from your inventory, and should allow you to regain rested bonuses.

See http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Lycanthropy_(Skyrim)#Curing_Lycanthropy for more info.

Comment: You must have misread the question, it starts with "After I _have cured_ my Lycanthropy"...

Comment: Yeah caught that and just made some edits.